# What is the meaning of phenotype could be represented by a number of different genotype

Tags: genetic-algorithms

I found this sentence in multiple sources but I didnt understand

in one thesis

> With a neutral representation each phenotype could be represented by a
> number of different genotype

and in another thesis

> it may be possible for neural networks with functionally equivalent
> topologies to be represented by a number of different genotypes

And in another source

[image: ![enter image description here]

> the genotypical representation:
> 010 001 100 0000 1100 0000 0000 0000 0011 0100 0000 0000
> However, the graph (phenotype) can also be represented by a number of
> different genotypes. E.g:

> 010 001 100 **0110** 1100 0000 **0011** 0000 0011 0100 0000 0000

> 010 001 100 0000 1100 0000 0000 0000 0011 0100 **1110 0100**

Up to my understanding the first phenotype is the representation of the graph, so why the second or third phenotypes are different representations. how did we come up with the bold genotypes

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The same function can be described in several ways.

If you're familiar with finite automata, then you should know that the same regular language ("phenotype") can be represented by many different finite automata ("genotype").

The same holds in many other cases, unless you choose an encoding which guarantees that every function has a unique description. It is not clear whether this is even desirable. For example, the genetic code has some redundancy which causes the same DNA sequence to encode the same proteins.

Comment: I did study it in formal languages but I forgot it tbh, do you mean the  DFA and NFA and PDA, if not, can you tell me which part do i need to revise

Comment: It’s just an example. There are also many Python programs that compute the same function, for example.